# TruConversion heatmap script with Next.js 11 Script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to install TruConversion's heatmap script on my Next.js 11 website.

On the homepage of TruConversion, they state that I should add their script before the `</head>` tag.

And the documentation of Next.js says that I shouldn't use the "next/script" in either a next/head component or in pages/_document.js.

So, I am confused. Where should I add that heatmap script?

Comment: _"they state that I should add their script before the tag"_ - What tag?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually, it is </head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

To use TruConversion's Heatmap you need to first load the [Tracking Code](https://help.truconversion.com/knowledgebase/manual-installation/) and then start [Heatmap Tracking](https://help.truconversion.com/knowledgebase/javascript-trigger-to-start-heatmap-tracking/).

You can place the tracking code `<script />` *either* in `pages/_document.js` using the `Head` component from [this example](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) or in `pages/index.js` with `<Script />` (note uppercase) `strategy="beforeInteractive"` using the new technique with `next/scripts` as demonstrated [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script).

Either approach will load the tracking script early on page load.

With that preloaded, you can now trigger TruConversion to start Heatmap Tracking anywhere in your app.

Comment: Hi Garrett, thanks for helping me out. I definitely want to use the new technique next/scripts. I have one confusion that if I use the <Script /> tag in the pages/index.js page, won't it be only installed on the home page? isn't the _app.js file the correct place for this <Script /> tag?